# Issue with order of execution

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-maps

I'm new with JS and I'm trying to fiddle a little with Google Maps. I found a few tutorials and examples, so I'm copy-pasting and trying to adapt it to my needs:

Here's what I need to do:

1. Load the map at a location
2. Load some markers from a file (I'm using JSON atm but I think I'll run into some problems later on)
3. Place the markers in the map
4. Put some checkboxes to toggle a group of markers.

Now, I was able to do it without step number 2 ([source](http://gonzalezmora.com/test/stackoverflow/gmaps/index2.html)), but I can't load them from a file. If you see the JS code in the next link (not the previous one), the features array is empty (check the console.log on line 14). From the Console output it seems it's because it's executing that line before the previous one (the getJSON one), but I don't know why that's happening. [Here](http://gonzalezmora.com/test/stackoverflow/gmaps/)'s the link.

Thanks in advance!

PS: regarding the JSON problem, I have to put some HTML code in the files (like on line 128 in main.js), should I just put everything in one line, or should I use another format instead of JSON? If so, which one do you recommend?

Comment: your source kinda needs to exist here on stackoverflow so that your question won't become useless after it's solved.

Comment: I doesn't let me add the code because of my reputation :(

Answer (score -1, accepted):

without looking further in your code and links, i would say try get the call Synchronous!
Like so:

**async: false**

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '...',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function() { },
    async: false
});
```

Comment: I think that did the trick! I'm trying to resolve another issues now, but it was the async call. Thank you reyaner!

Comment: Yeah, I don't know :( Plus I don't have enough reputation to vote up, but I will once I get it. Thanks again!